# Jhipster Prod Build failure along with Cloudfoundry error Not Found

Tags: java, maven, jhipster, cloud-foundry, yarnpkg

Jhipster prod profile build is getting failed giving access denied error on execution of

> yarn install

It had generated `.war` in earlier build with dev profile. On uploading the .war to cloudfoundry via subgenerator the app status is running. But, application is not accessible.

> Error on accessing root:

```
Sorry, an error has occurred.
Status: Not Found (Not Found)
Message: Not Found
```

Maven Build error :

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\codelab\a2z\dhulai>mvnw -Pprod -DskipTests
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Dhulai 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.13.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ dhulai >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:copy-resources (default-resources) @ dhulai ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] Copying 23 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ dhulai ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] Copying 23 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M1:enforce (enforce-versions) @ dhulai ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:copy-resources (docker-resources) @ dhulai ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9:prepare-agent (pre-unit-tests) @ dhulai ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:C:\\Users\\patelri\\.m2\\repository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.7.9\\org.jacoco.agent-0.7.9-runtime.jar=destfile=C:\\codelab\\
a2z\\dhulai\\target\\test-results\\coverage\\jacoco\\jacoco.exec -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx256m
[INFO]
[INFO] --- git-commit-id-plugin:2.2.4:revision (default) @ dhulai ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.13.RELEASE:build-info (default) @ dhulai ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:yarn (yarn install) @ dhulai ---
[INFO] Running 'yarn install' in C:\codelab\a2z\dhulai
[ERROR] Access is denied.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.581 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-04T16:50:28+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 35M/422M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:yarn (yarn install) on project dhulai: Failed to run task: 'yarn install' failed. org.ap
ache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Configuration file of Jhipster:

> .yo-rc.json

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "com.np.dhulai",
      "nativeLanguage": "en"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "4.14.4",
    "baseName": "dhulai",
    "packageName": "com.np.dhulai",
    "packageFolder": "com/np/dhulai",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "cacheProvider": "ehcache",
    "enableHibernateCache": true,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
    "prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "jwtSecretKey": "DELETED",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "useSass": false,
    "clientPackageManager": "yarn",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "languages": [
      "en",
      "nl"
    ]
  }
}
```

Other Details
OS : Windows 10 Enterprise 64 bit
[image]

**[Update 1]**
Updated pom file to have verbose flag and the stack trace post it suggest

```
   [INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:install-node-and-yarn (install node and yarn) @ dhulai ---
[INFO] Installing node version v10.4.0
[INFO] Copying node binary from C:\Users\patelri\.m2\repository\com\github\eirslett\node\10.4.0\node-10.4.0-win-x64.exe to C:\codelab\a2z\dhulai\node\node.exe
[INFO] Installed node locally.
[INFO] Installing Yarn version v1.9.4
[INFO] Downloading https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases/download/v1.9.4/yarn-v1.9.4.tar.gz to C:\Users\patelri\.m2\repository\com\github\eirslett\yarn\1.9.4\yarn
-1.9.4.tar.gz
[INFO] No proxies configured
[INFO] No proxy was configured, downloading directly
Aug 04, 2018 6:21:53 PM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
WARNING: Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: has_recent_activity=1; path=/; expires=Sat, 04 Aug 2018 13:51:55 -0000". Invalid 'expires' attribute: Sat, 04 Aug 2018 1
3:51:55 -0000
Aug 04, 2018 6:21:53 PM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
WARNING: Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: logged_in=no; domain=.github.com; path=/; expires=Wed, 04 Aug 2038 12:51:55 -0000; secure; HttpOnly". Invalid 'expires'
attribute: Wed, 04 Aug 2038 12:51:55 -0000
[INFO] Unpacking C:\Users\patelri\.m2\repository\com\github\eirslett\yarn\1.9.4\yarn-1.9.4.tar.gz into C:\codelab\a2z\dhulai\node\yarn
[INFO] Installed Yarn locally.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:yarn (webpack build dev) @ dhulai ---
[INFO] yarn not inheriting proxy config from Maven
[INFO] Running 'yarn run webpack:build' in C:\codelab\a2z\dhulai
[ERROR] Access is denied.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 49.223 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-04T18:22:33+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 39M/330M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:yarn (webpack build dev) on project dhulai: Failed to run task: 'yarn run webpack:build'
 failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
```

However, if I independently execute `yarn run webpack:build` it has no issue with the access permission

Comment: Yes I am using the cloudfoundry subgenerator. I will go through the link and update

Comment: yes without the CF generator it fails with the plan maven wrapper as well. The issue reported seems has "Access is denied" for the root folder, but there is no hints as the terminal/cmd prompt opened with the admin rights. Is there any way to bypass this?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. Try to change `node.version` and `yarn.version` both to lower version in your pom.xml (May be to the version that was install on your computer when generating the project). I'm not your about what is going wrong, but this worked for me. Hope It will help